# How to retrieve data from oracle database in c# windows application without data adapter

Tags: c#

How to retrieve data from oracle database in c# windows application without filling  DataAdapter?

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched?

Comment: I apologize for posting a ridiculous question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want direct control and writing your own queries, then DataReader https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader?view=netframework-4.8

Otherwise, read up on Linq to Sql or EntityFramework. I'm sure there other alternatives out there.